# input:checked and option:selected selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 variables storing 2 selectors,

```
<script>
    var checkedFilters = $(this).find('input:checked');
    var selectedFilters = $(this).find('option:selected');
</script>
```

i want to use them in one variable
is there way to do it?
i mean i want one selector to handle both input:checked and option:selected in the same time
like this:

```
var filters = $(this).find('input:checked' or 'option:selected');
```

thank you in advinced

Comment: `var filters = $(this).find('input:checked, option:selected');`

Comment: what is `this` first of all? you are pointing `window` here

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to use **[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**:

```
var filters = $(this).find('input:checked,option:selected');
```